# Конвертировать файл DOC to PDF libreoffice-core

Tags: php, файлы, libre-office

Всем добрый день!
У меня встала задача, выводить на сайте файлы DOC в виде PDF.
Исходный файл DOC храниться в базе данных в виде бинарного кода.

Возможно ли с помощью PHP + libreoffice-core не создавая в директории сервера никаких временных файлов отдать в браузере клиенту файл PDF.

Если с помощью libreoffice-core это невозможно то с помощью чего я смогу реализовать свою задачу? Посоветуйте.

Comment: Начните вот отсюда
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538584/convert-word-doc-docx-and-excel-xls-xlsx-to-pdf-with-php

Comment: avocado03.. Не совсем то что нужно. Там описывается конвертация физических файлов. А мне нужно аналогичное конвертирование но без создания файла а только по его Бинарному коду переведя его в PDF и отобразить в Браузере, Грубо говоря сам Бинарник DOC перекодировать в Бинарник PDF. Отображение в Браузере Бинарника PDF я уже отладил.